# Change text color dynamically AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I struggle thinking "The Angular Way" so this is undoubtedly a simple problem, but I'm trying to have it so when I click a button (which will eventually be colored) the text changes to that color. Here is essentially the code:

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ColorCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.changeColor = function(value){
        return {"color:" value };
    }

    $scope.turnGreen = function (){
        //what to do here?
    }

    $scope.turnBlue = function() {
        //and here?
    }
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ColorCtrl">

    <button ng-click="turnBlue()">Make text blue</button>
    <button ng-click="turnGreen()">Make text green</button>

    <p ng-style="changeColor(value)">I should be either green or blue!</p>

</div>
```

I know I could easily use jQuery to select the text I want to work with, but I don't want to do that. Do i need to give my paragraph a model? Any push in the right direction is greatly appreciated - thank you.

Comment: Have you seen the example here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngStyle It does it without a controller.

Comment: I should be shamed for asking a question without checking the corresponding doc. Appreciate your help though, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: As I mentioned below, I created a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/eLOvocu/1/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could do this way:

Define ng-class directive and value as `colorClass` which will be set in the scope.

```
<p ng-class="customStyle.colorClass">I should be either green or blue!</p>
```

and do:

```
 $scope.customStyle = {};
 $scope.turnGreen = function (){
    $scope.customStyle.colorClass = "green";
}

$scope.turnBlue = function() {
    $scope.customStyle.colorClass = "blue";
}
```

and some rules:

```
.green{
  color:green;
}
.blue{
  color:blue;
}
```

or with inline style

```
 <p ng-style="customStyle.style">I should be either green or blue!</p>
```

and

```
$scope.customStyle = {};
$scope.turnGreen = function (){
    //what to do here?
    $scope.customStyle.style = {"color":"green"};
}

$scope.turnBlue = function() {
    $scope.customStyle.style = {"color":"blue"};
}
```

Comment: I will recommend changing the $scope.colorClass to be $scope.data.colorClass to avoid the prototype issue in more complex scenarios. My example is similar to yours: http://jsbin.com/eLOvocu/1/

Comment: I would try to explain what I mean but there is not enough space here to explain. To better understand, kindly view these two links: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes and the next three minutes of this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m

Comment: So then the to summarize the prototype chain is not consulted when resolving primitive properties and so you should use an object as the property instead so that properties don't get shadowed.